# Redirect URL to correct user page

Tags: php, mysql, html, redirect

I was just looking for a little help on the following, unfortunately I haven't been able to find a solution, perhaps due to not knowing what to call it exactly. I can only find solutions for doing the reverse of what I require.

At present I have a user page set up, which can be accessed via a URL as follows:

> [DOMAIN_NAME]/client/?client=3

I would like to be able for users to type:

> [DOMAIN_NAME]/apples

and be directed to the the prior URL, assuming apples is a valid user name.

I am using PHP and I know I could have just set it up for users to have their own folders etc. but was wondering if there is a URL redirect solution for this. Preferably one that would keep the url as the user has typed it, but show the real information.

Thanks,
Cillian

Comment: u can be use header("location:[DOMAIN_NAME]/apples");

Comment: That would redirect from the full URL to the shortened URL, which is not what I would like. Also there is nothing actually called "apples" within the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fullurl = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$username = $fullurl[count($fullurl)-1];
echo $username;
```

then check $username e.i it is valid user or not if valid user then redirect to your desire page.

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/userfolder/yourpage.php?userid=$userid');
```

Comment: I understand this would work, but if the user has typed in apple in the url, it's going to look for an apple folder or file which does not exist. So I don't have a place to put the code.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use .htaccess redirect Method 
See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I looked at that method, but I don't really know how to make it work for my example. Especially as there are folders there that I don't want redirected.